# Calculating sample mean from confidence interval, confidence level and sample size

Tags: statistics

How do I calculate the sample mean given these variables (confidence interval, confidence level and sample size)? I have everything except (obviously) the sample mean, and I also lack the standard deviation seemingly.

Comment: what is the confidence interval for? what is the underlying distribution for which the confidence interval is constructed?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the sample mean is the midpoint of the confidence interval.